# Removing permissions in a user profile

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Remove user ticket permissions from user profiles

We defined a lot of the user profiles with permissions for viewing, editing, adding, and search ticket or cases.  This was a mistake.

I am retrieving the permissions using URL: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/7227801/getPermissions.json

This returns the JSON containing all permissions assigned to the user profile.

How do I remove all permissions associated with tickets or cases in user profiles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below rest call example:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userId]/removeBulkPortalPermission
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters":[
    [
        {
            "keyName":"TICKET_EDIT"
        },
        {
            "keyName":"TICKET_ADD"
        },
            {
            "keyName":"TICKET_VIEW"
        }

    ]
  ]
}
```

Add to the json body all the "keyName" permissions that you want to remove.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you!